# react-router-redux: Routes change but components are not displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm attempting to set up routing using react-router-redux with Immutable.js reducers.

I've set up the store using `syncHistoryWithStore`, and when I click on a `Link`, I can see that the correct `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` action is dispatched, that the store is correctly updated with the location information to the `routing` key of the base reducer, and that the URL is changing to the correct location.

The problem is that the components do not update. If I load the page at a specific location, I see the correct component, but no other components are displayed once I click a `Link` after that.

I've included what I think are the relevant files (with some irrelevant information redacted):

initialize.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { routerMiddleware, syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import reducers from 'reducers'

const browserHistoryRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)

const middlewares = [browserHistoryRouterMiddleware]

/* Create store */
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  undefined,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
  ),
)

/* Configure history */
const createSelectLocationState = () => {
  let prevRoutingState, prevRoutingStateJS

  return (state) => {
    const routingState = state.get('routing')
    if (typeof prevRoutingState === 'undefined' || prevRoutingState !== routingState) {
      prevRoutingState = routingState
      prevRoutingStateJS = routingState.toJS()
    }
    return prevRoutingState
  }
}

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: createSelectLocationState(),
})

export { store, history }
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { store, history } from 'initialize'
import Root from 'components/Root'

render(
  <Root store={store} history={history} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Root.js:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import routes from 'routes'

const Root = ({ store, history }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      {routes}
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default Root
```

`routes` is just a nested list of `Route` and `IndexRoute` components, starting with `<Route path='/' component={App} />`. When I `console.log` App's children prop, I can see that there are children passed when it first renders and it correctly renders them, but at no other point do I see any more console feedback on children changing.

Logged action (state is an Immutable Map, but I run `toJS()` for logging purposes):
[image: Logged Action]

What am I missing that should change the displayed components as I move through my routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was returning `prevRoutingState` from `createSelectLocationHistory` rather than `prevRoutingStateJS`.